# Oracle implicit conversion warning

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way how to force PL/SQL compiler to tell me (using a compilation hint or an error) that I am trying to put a string into an integer? In some cases, the implicit conversion will handle it for me, but I don't want that. I always want to know that there is a type mismatch.

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 5):

You can enable compiler warnings for compiled PL/SQL with

```
alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:all';
```

The particular warning for implicit conversion is `PLW-07204`, which you can enable on its own with:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:7204';
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60f61867ce08f860cb75ed11263bea4d)

This will only notify you about implicit conversion happening inside static SQL statements where the conversion could go either way and cause a performance problem.

Comment: Nice tip. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Ah, nice! Today I did learn something new. Thank you, Andrew.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

I tried it and it seems that this is working only for SELECTs, but not working for variable assignment, see [dbfiddle - package example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ba85ae0828eeb2ba57bb7627a247c12)

Comment: I guess that would be because the performance implications are not the same and the rules of conversion are quite obvious (the variable being set cannot change data type so it is always the value on the right that undergoes implicit conversion). If all warnings doesn't catch it then there almost certainly isn't a way to catch it currently - you may want to raise an enhancement request with Oracle but there's no guarantee they'll take action. I'll edit my answer to make this exception clear.